# Как правильно создать и прочитать последнюю строку файла?

Tags: c#

Я хочу создать файл (если он еще не создан) и прочитать последнюю строку:

```
if (!File.Exists(DirectoryPath))
{
    File.Create(DirectoryPath);
}
string lastLine = File.ReadLines(DirectoryPath).LastOrDefault();
```

Но мне возвращается исключение:"Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу". Что я делаю не правильно?

Comment: `DirectoryPath` переводится как путь к папке. Вы уверены, что это путь именно к конкретному файлу?

Comment: В какой строке выбрасывается исключение?

Comment: Если файла нет, вы его создаёте (пустой!) и сразу же читаете из _пустого_ файла. Не хватает записи в файл.

Comment: @V-Mor DirectoryPath ошибся в названии переменной, этот путь ведет к файлу. Исключение выбрасывается в строке с объявлением переменной lastLine

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov но ведь я использую метод LastOrDefault()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При вызове `File.Create` создаётся файловый поток, вы должны его закрыть, прежде чем опять открывать этот файл. У вас файл занят этим потоком. Пример из [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.io.file.create?view=netframework-4.5), где файловый поток закрывается автоматически с помощью `using`:

```
    using (FileStream fs = File.Create(path))
    {
        byte[] info = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes("This is some text in the file.");
        // Add some information to the file.
        fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length);
    }
```